# Shutting down web server for maintenance

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, cron, maintenance

Note: I am new to this situation!

How do we manage to to redirect every request during maintenance to a page which says the site is under maintenance mode?

I want to automate this process (through cron):

1. Shutdown apache
2. Do maintenance (During this time every request should be redirected to the maintenance page)
3. Start apache

In point 2 how do I redirect each request when apache is down or how do people manage this (automated)?
Appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Comment: Looking for ideas like this?  http://serverfault.com/questions/23485/how-to-show-a-maintenance-page-for-website-when-our-network-is-down

Comment: RewriteRule .* 503.php [L]

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to make the sites unacessible during maintenance and use one file per virtual host like ubuntu and debian do (`/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `sites-disabled`) you can just disable the sites removing the links from sites-available (or moving the files out). 
You can also create a 'catch all' site and enable it showing a 'maintenance message'.

Other option is to use iptables to redirect all traffic on the http port to another port on the server, where you can run a secondary webserver (lighttpd or nginx or anything really small that can serve static html pages). The rule would be:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ethX -d <server ip> –dport 80 -j DNAT –to <server ip>:<new port>
```

You can also redirect to another server/port completely.

Answer (score 1):

Apache needs to remain running to serve websites, but you can configure it to send all requests to a maintenance webpage using the DocumentRoot directive.  Assuming you create a page for maintenance notification inside of a maintenance directory, it would look like this:

Normal Operations:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/maintenance"
```

Maintenance Operations:  just comment out the normal and uncomment the maintenance line:

```
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
DoucmentRoot "/var/www/html/maintenance"
```

Then just reload Apache to activate the changes: `/etc/init.d/httpd reload`.  When you finish, just reverse the process.

Note that if you have multiple VirtualHosts you would need to make that DocumentRoot change for each one.  There might be (probably is) a simpler method - for a simple setup this is what I do.

Comment: What if you have to pull down your apache, how do you redirect requests?

Comment: If you HAVE to pull down apache, you need to have at least some server intercepting requests in that time.   Either by another server temporarily answering on that IP address, or a front end load balancer redirecting traffic to a "we're in maintenance" web server.

Answer (score 0):

I can not talk about Apache, but here is how I do it in IIS (which, indicentally, has IMHO a better interface for that).

- I have the website in a folder (OBVIOUSLY)
- I have another site in another folder that is the "maintenance site".
- I just change the folders on the site before maintenance.

IIS / ASP.NET also have a nice mechanism where a "block file" turns the whole site into maintenance mode. This is done by putting a page "app_offline.htm" into the site's root folder. The negatie side odf that is that you can not test the site under another URL while this is in (which may be good for a last internal check that all things work). So, I went over to have a maintenance site.

Having a separate folder and redirecting the site is IMHO the fastest way.

Comment: What if you have a lot of virtual hosts served by a single server instance? Do you put lots of app_offline.htm for each of them?

Comment: That depends. App_offline in a host - depends. Do I maintain all the sites at the same time? Normally not. Then naturally no app_offline in the ones not under maintenance.